# How to fetch data entries from mysql in jsp using struts2 in eclipse environment?

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, jsp, struts2

**EventDropDown.java** //Page 1

```
package com.tutorialspoint.struts2;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.ArrayList;
//import java.util.List;


import com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetMetaData;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")`enter code here`
public class EventDropdownAction extends ActionSupport {

    ArrayList<Event> eventList=new ArrayList<Event>();

    public ArrayList<Event> getList() {
        return eventList;
    }


    public void setList(ArrayList<Event> eventList) {
        this.eventList = eventList;
    }
     private String eventName;
     public String execute()
     {
        logger.info("Message-execute");
        return ""; 
     }
    public String getEventList() 
    {
Connection conn = null;
 try {
             String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bookmyshow_dates";
             Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
             conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, "dra2", "dr@2");
        "CASE \r\n" + 
                    "   WHEN DATEDIFF(DATE,NOW()) = 0 THEN CONCAT('Today',',',DAY(DATE),' ',MONTHNAME(DATE))\r\n" + 
                    "   WHEN DATEDIFF(DATE,NOW()) = 1 THEN CONCAT('Tomorrow',',',DAY(DATE),' ',MONTHNAME(DATE))\r\n" + 
                    "   WHEN DATEDIFF(DATE,NOW()) > 1 THEN CONCAT(DAYNAME(DATE),',',DAY(DATE),' ',MONTHNAME(DATE))\r\n" + 
                    "END AS EventDay\r\n" + 
                    "FROM EVENTS\r\n" + 
                    "WHERE DATE_FORMAT(DATE,'%d/%m/%Y') >= DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%d/%m/%Y')";
 String sql ="SELECT * FROM user3333";
             PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

             ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
             ResultSetMetaData rsmd = (ResultSetMetaData) rs.getMetaData();
             int numberOfColumns = rsmd.getColumnCount();
             int rowCount=0;
             if(rs.last()){
                 rowCount= rs.getRow();
              } else {
                  rowCount= 0; //just cus I like to always do some kind else statement.
              }
              while (rs.next()) {
Event objEvent=new Event();
                 objEvent.setEventId(rs.getInt("EventId"));
                 objEvent.setEventName(rs.getString("EventName"));
                 objEvent.setEventDay(rs.getString("EventDay"));

                 Event objEvent=new Event(rs.getInt(1),rs.getString(2));
                 eventList.add(objEvent);
                ret = SUCCESS;
 }
          } catch (Exception e) 
{
  ret = ERROR;
 return "error";
          } 
          finally {
             if (conn != null) {
                try {
                   conn.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
             }
          }
          return "eventDropdown";
    }
}
```

**Event.java** //Page 2

```
package com.tutorialspoint.struts2;

public class Event {
    public int EventId;
    public String EventName,EventDay;

    Event()
    {
        this.EventId = 0;
        this.EventName = "";
    }
    Event(int eventId, String eventName)
    {
        this.EventId = eventId;
        this.EventName = eventName;
    }

    public int getEventId() {
        return EventId;
    }
    public void setEventId(int id) {
        this.EventId = id;
    }
    public String getEventName() {
        return EventName;
    }
    public void setEventName(String name) {
        this.EventName = name;
    }
    public String getEventDay() {
        return EventDay;
    }
    public void setEventDay(String eventDay) {
        this.EventDay = eventDay;
    }
}
```

**Error.jsp** //Page 3

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
error page.
</body>
</html>

**Success.jsp** //Page 3

<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
success page.

</body>
</html>
```

**EventDayDropdown.jsp** //Page 4

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
     <s:select name="username" label="Username" list="{'Mike','John','Smith'}" />
     <br>
     <s:select label="Select Event" name="ddlEvent" headerKey="0" headerValue="--Select--" list="{eventList}" listKey="{EventId}" listValue="{EventName}"/>
<%-- <s:select label="Select Event" name="ddlEvent" headerKey="0" headerValue="--Select--" list="{eventList}" /> --%>
<%-- <s:select name="event" list="eventList" listKey="eventId" listValue="eventName" headerKey="0" headerValue="--Event--" label="Select a event" /> --%>
</body>
</html>
```

**Struts.xml** //Page 5

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
   "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
   "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
<struts>

   <package name="helloworld" extends="struts-default">
      <action name="event" class="com.tutorialspoint.struts2.EventDropdownAction" 
            method="getEventList">
            <result name="success">/success.jsp</result>
            <result name="failure">/error.jsp</result>
            <result name="eventDropdown">/EventDayDropdown.jsp</result>
      </action>
     </package>

</struts>
```

These are files that is done with struts 2 in Eclipse IDE.

My database contains

3 Columns with atrributes

```
Event_Id  1, 2, 3, 4 
EventName 2 states, Hobbit, Gravity,Gladiator.
Dates 20/5/2014, 21/5/2014, 21/5/2014, 23/5/2014
```

Like this.
Please help me. I am beginner.

Answer (score 0):

Try trace your code block by block my using logging framework or simply System.out.println statements and but them in the start middle before db call after db call during db fetch and before return from the methods and see, what are exactly your problems? is it in the db or from struts2 or from Java code.

Another solution is to create separate applications, create a standlone project to fetch data from mysql database and test it in the console and create a a struts2 project with static 
contents instead of trying fetching the data from database and see if the web application
provide what you need. Finally join both projects. so if any errors happened you can solve
it separately.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I did MySQL connection successfully.